# Is flexbox considered part of vanilla CSS?

Tags: css

I'm just confused because it's a thing with a specific name that people use a lot, as if it's separate from vanilla, but it's just a thing that's built in. Would I need to mention that I know how to use flexbox on a skill list?

Comment: yes considered , you should use flexbox if you want to make website responsive, also bootstrap is built on flexbox

Comment: If you do, your CV/resume would just be thrown out.